# Don't know how to fix this error, trying to write a method but keep getting the same error

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a method where it will return an integer value of where the first vowel is located in the string "w". I've already created the fist method to find if there is a vowel at a certain location, but when I tried using that method in the new method it says "cannot find symbol - method isVowel()." Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? I've been told already that I must use the method isVowel in the new method. The error highlights the term "isVowel()" that is used in the last method.

```
public class words
    {
        private String w;

        /**
         * Default Constructor for objects of class words
         */
        public words()
        {
            // initialise instance variables
            w="";
        }

        /**
         * Assignment constructor
         */
        public words(String assignment)
        {
            w=assignment;
        }

        /**
         * Copy constructor
         */
        public words(words two)
        {
            w=two.w;
        }

        /**
         * Pre: 0<=i<length( )
         * returns true if the character at location i is a vowel (‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i', ‘o’, ‘u’ only), false if not
         */
        public boolean isVowel(int i)
        {
            if (w.charAt(i)=='a')  
                return true; 
            else if (w.charAt(i)=='e')
                return true;
            else if (w.charAt(i)=='i')
                return true;
            else if (w.charAt(i)=='o')
                return true;
            else if (w.charAt(i)=='u')
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        /**
         * determines whether the first vowel in the String is at location 0, 1, 2, or 3 (don’t worry about exceptions)
         */
        private int findFirstVowel()
        {
            return w.indexOf(w.isVowel());
        }
```

Comment: `w.isVowel()` - `w` is a String and it does not have that method. That's what the error is indicating.

Comment: Okay, well if I'm required to use that method in this method - how do you suggest I use it?

Comment: You need to fundamentally rethink your `findFirstVowel()` method.  Start with explaining how you would do this in plain English, then try to translate that to code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the valid indices of `w`, and then you can use your `isVowel(int)` method to check. Something like,

```
private int findFirstVowel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (isVowel(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Also, you might consider reducing your `if-else` chain to a basic `return` in `isVowel` (and I note you currently only match lower-case letters, but we could also make it case-insensitive). Like,

```
public boolean isVowel(int i) 
{
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(i));
    return ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is also:

```
public boolean isVowel(int i) 
{
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(w.charAt(i));
    switch(ch) {
        case 'a: case'e': case'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, 'y' is often a vowel. Your algorithm gives the incorrect number of vowels for words like "system", "syzygy", "why", etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, most times people don't consider "y" to be a vowel so it is left out.